# Sending buffered data through a socket from Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, binary, buffered

I develop the first part of an Android application that allows to broadcast video stream through the network. Currently, I'm sending the video in a very direct way, like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
```

But unfortunately, it is not very fluid. I want to buffered the data stream before sending it through the socket. One of the way I tried is to write the stream in a file using the [Android API for recording media](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), and to use another thread to stream the file to the server on a conputer.

So my problem is: how can I send by a socket a file which is still under writing?
As [BufferedInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) has not a blocking method for reading, I tried to do things like this one, but without any success

```
while (inputStream.available() >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
  inputStream.read(buffer);
  outputStream.write(buffer);
}
outputStream.flush();
```

But when i'm doing that, if the network is faster than the datastream, I get quickly out of the loop.

Is there a 'good' way to do that? I though about doing active waiting but it is not a good solution, especially for mobiles. Another way is to do something like this :

```
while (true) {
  while (inputStream.available() < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    wait(TIME); 
  }
  inputStream.read(buffer);
  outputStream.write(buffer);
}
outputStream.flush();
```

But it sound quite dirty for me... Is there sleeker solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a pretty way of doing this, but one option might be to create a local socket pair, use the 'client' end of the pair as the MediaRecorder output fd, and buffer between the local-server socket and the remote-server. This way, you can block on the local-server until there is data.

Another possibility is to use a file-based pipe/fifo (so the disk doesn't fill up), but I can't remember if the Java layer exposes mkfifo functionality.

In any event, you probably want to look at [FileReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileReader.html), since reads on that should block.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Ok Phil, thanks for the solution! I implemented it and it seems to work nicely :)

Comment: Hi, Can you please help to share some sample code so that it can help me as well 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I do in these situations if simply fill up a byte array (my buffer) until either I've hit the end of the data I'm about to transmit, or the buffer is full.  In which case the buffer is ready to be passed to my Socket transmission logic.  Admittedly, I do not do this on video or audio though … only on “regular” data.

Something worth noting is this will give a "janky" user experience to the recipient of that data (it might look like the network is stopping for short periods then running normally again ... the time the buffer is using to fill up).  So if you have to use a buffered approach on either video or audio be careful on what buffer size you decide to work with.

For things like video it's been my experence to use streaming based logic versus buffered, but you apparently have some different and interesting requirements.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately in this case, the buffer solution cannot work because of the data volume... And the streaming with very smalls packets -- and high numbers of them -- leads to data loss in the mesh network I use.

Comment: I admit I was curious when you asked for a buffered solution, but I agree that for video buffered makes for a poor answer.  Interesting that the streaming won't seem to work - in this case at least - for you either.  That's always been one of the tradeoffs with streaming techniques is a few packets taking a coffee break.  Most of the time this is unperceptable to the user, but I can see how the network can make that statement void.